# Android webview in viewpager

Tags: android, html, webview

Got a viewpager with webview. Webview loads an url . Loaded url might contain a slideshow . Problem slideshow doesnt swipe , because viewpager swipe works over it. How to fix it ??

Comment: This one is interesting as the on intercept touch event won't work

Comment: Tehnically works , only in other way for example normally people swap East-West or West-East , but here it works as North-East,North-West,South-East,South-West

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That might be hard to do. Only thing that comes to my mind atm is creating view that will have knowledge of content thats within(view group) it and then calculating touch areas and then passing touch data to correct views, It will involve some view extending :)

The simplest way would be making view pager not swipable but rather reacting to button clicks underneath it

Comment: we founded how to hack this issue , but simple users dont want such solution :)

Comment: Please share your hack if not for users at least we want to know